# SQL Server: wait for new row

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, locking, service-broker

How can I wait for a new row appearing in a SQL Server table from a .NET client application?

Background: I'd like to build a message queue based on a table. I don't want to use Service Broker because I want messages to be structured and strongly typed. Using a normal table I can have relations with other tables, too.

Comment: *GASP* Trigger on the "waiting for" table and a job watching your new table to fire off.  Service Broker is really awesome...just saying.

Comment: Yeah Service Broker would be perfect but it does not allow using nice tables as queues (right? I have to use nasty XML blobs).

Comment: You can write a proc to peek at the queue...  You can query XML (does not perform very well)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The normal way is to use polling, but if you really need immediate events you can use the [`SqlDependency`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.aspx) class to get an event when the result of a query changes.

Comment: I'd probably need to create a new dependency after every message that I have dequeued.

Comment: SqlDependency uses ServiceBroker...  I was going to mention it too.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because SqlDependency automates receiving an update notification using Service Broker under the hood. I'll register a notification for the query "select id from tab where id > @lastReceivedMessageID".

Answer (score 2):

You need to either poll or get notified.

Polling would require the client to query the table periodically, either using a predicate or for `count(*)`. This is probably not a great solution.

It could be a cheap but useful notification system to put a trigger in the table and send a message to a listener in the client.

Answer (score 1):

In our application we use System.Threading.Timer to poll database table. Once new message is available it is being processed. If processing is successful, message is removed from DB.